# "Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Trying '_raw_ecb.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so' when running Lambda on python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I am trying my some encryption and description with python and trying to run it on lambda.

I am getting the below error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Cannot load native module 'Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb': Trying '_raw_ecb.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so': /var/task/Crypto/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, Trying '_raw_ecb.abi3.so': /var/task/Crypto/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.abi3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory, Trying '_raw_ecb.so': /var/task/Crypto/Util/../Cipher/_raw_ecb.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory",
  "errorType": "OSError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 234, in load_module\n    return load_source(name, filename, file)\n",
    "  File \"/var/lang/lib/python3.8/imp.py\", line 171, in load_source\n    module = _load(spec)\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 702, in _load\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 671, in _load_unlocked\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>\", line 783, in exec_module\n",
    "  File \"<frozen importlib._bootstrap>\", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/billFetch.py\", line 1, in <module>\n    from Crypto.Cipher import AES\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/Crypto/Cipher/__init__.py\", line 27, in <module>\n    from Crypto.Cipher._mode_ecb import _create_ecb_cipher\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/Crypto/Cipher/_mode_ecb.py\", line 35, in <module>\n    raw_ecb_lib = load_pycryptodome_raw_lib(\"Crypto.Cipher._raw_ecb\", \"\"\"\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/Crypto/Util/_raw_api.py\", line 297, in load_pycryptodome_raw_lib\n    raise OSError(\"Cannot load native module '%s': %s\" % (name, \", \".join(attempts)))\n"
  ]
}
```

Here is my code:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
 
key = 'assignmentToSetu'
key = key.encode('utf8')
print (type(key)) 
cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
msg =cipher.encrypt('TechTutorialsX!!TechTutorialsX!!'.encode('utf8'))
print (type(msg))
 
print(msg.hex())
 
decipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_ECB)
print(decipher.decrypt(msg))
```

I am sure the issue is with the "pycryptodome-3.10.1.dist-info" library as it is not compatible with lambda OS as this code is running fine on my local system which is also on python 3.8

Could any one help me out with this?

Comment: How did you add the library to lambda?

Comment: @Marcin   download in my local by "pip install -t ." and zipped it and then uploaded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience, the most relable way to include dependencies to lambda functions is through [lambda layers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-layers.html) and the use of **docker** as described in the [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-layer-simulated-docker/).

Thus you can add `pycrypto` to your function as follows:

1. Create empty folder, e.g. `mylayer`.
2. Go to the folder and create `requirements.txt` file with the content of

```
echo pycrypto > ./requirements.txt
```

3. Run the following docker command:

The command will create layer for python3.8:

```
docker run -v "$PWD":/var/task "lambci/lambda:build-python3.8" /bin/sh -c "pip install -r requirements.txt -t python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/; exit"
```

4. Archive the layer as zip:

```
zip -9 -r mylayer.zip python
```

5. Create lambda layer based on `mylayer.zip` in the AWS Console. Don't forget to specify `Compatible runtime` to `python3.8`.
6. Add the the layer created in step 5 to your function.
7. I tested the layer using your code.

It  works **correctly**:

```
<class 'bytes'>
<class 'bytes'>
3f1f642e3ef7a8e568f1ed5a7f02cb823f1f642e3ef7a8e568f1ed5a7f02cb82
b'TechTutorialsX!!TechTutorialsX!!'
```

Comment: how would the lambda code lock while calling package from layers?

Comment: @sumanthshetty There is no difference to your lambda code.

Comment: did you install the "pycrypto"? i have windows local machine. 
what will be the content of requirements.txt

Comment: @sumanthshetty `pycrypto` in `requirements.txt`. I used linux to create the layer. If you have issues with windows, you may try setting up ec2 linux instance.

Comment: how do i move the library from my ec2 machine to local machine

Comment: For windows, `winscp` is probably the best way. Or you can copy to s3 from instance (given instance role).

Comment: could you help me out of this? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66205150/trying-to-connect-to-socket-io-punning-on-node-on-ec2-machine-from-react-app-hos

Comment: @sumanthshetty I will have a look. How did it go with this question? Was the answer helpful?

Comment: i need to try it out. 
occupied with this now

Comment: @sumanthshetty No problem. Sadly I'm not too familiar with socker.io, thus can't help much with the new question.

Comment: could you help me out with this
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66259126/cloudfront-showing-the-request-could-not-be-satisfied-502-error-when-trying-to