# cloudfront showing "The request could not be satisfied 502 error" when trying to connect to ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudfront

I am trying to point CloudFront for my ec2 machine.

under origin, I am giving the public DNS name of the ec2 :(e.g. ec2-52-64-xxx-xxx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com)"

But I am getting this error:

[image]

I have opened 443 port also open on my ec2.

How can I solve this error?

Comment: Did you setup HTTPs on your instance with valid public SSL certifcate, thus are using port 443?

Comment: yes, I have set up a valid SSL created by ACM. 
I used SSL while creating CloudFront

Comment: I mean on the instance itself, not CF. You wrote "opened 443 port", which suggests that on the instance you have SSL certificate. This is separate from CF.

Comment: no i dont have a ssl on instance. 
i have my security group open on 443

Comment: If you don't use CF, does your website work on the instance? Can you access it?

Comment: yes, i can access it. But wanted to have https involved and also a distribution

Comment: On what port do you access it, 443?

Comment: I am testing it. 
I have an Apache server running which redirects the request to the app running. 
whenever I hit the IP it redirects. But, when I create a cloud front and check with it's own domain I get this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the chat discussion.

The application on the instance works over **HTTP and port 80**. It does not server HTTPS traffic in itself. So if you want to use the current setup with CF, you need to allow port 80 (not 443) and in CF using HTTP for origin protocol (not HTTPS). The way this works is that HTTPS and SSL will be only between client and CF, not between CF and your instance:

```
client----(HTTPS:443)--->CF----(HTTP:80)---->EC2 instance
```

As you can see above, there is a security issue. All traffic between CF and your instance will be in **pain text** over the internet. To rectify this, you need to add HTTPS to your instance. There are **two ways** for that:

1. Add **load balancer** in-front of your instance, and deploy custom domain on it with SSL from ACM and HTTPS listener. So the traffic will be:

```
client----(HTTPS:443)--->CF----(HTTPS:443)---->ALB---(private HTTP:80)--->EC2 instance
```

2. Setup SSL on your instance directly. For this you can't use ACM (except when your instance is [enclave](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-nitro-enclaves-isolated-ec2-environments-to-process-confidential-data/)). Instead, you have to use **third-party SSL provider**. Common choice is https://letsencrypt.org/. Then you setup your Apache with the SSL certificate to serve HTTPS traffic. Subsequently, you will have:

```
client----(HTTPS:443)--->CF----(HTTPS:443)---->EC2 instance
```

Comment: should I also change the viewer protocol?
currently set up with redirect HTTP to HTTPS

Comment: i tried first step. 
client----(HTTPS:443)--->CF----(HTTP:80)---->EC2 instance I am getting "invalid host header" error

Comment: could it be with the origin path value?

Comment: I am getting "invalid host header" when I hit the domain name, 
not able to point out what is causing it

Comment: Do you do any host checks in your app? Maybe its not expecting connections from CF?

Comment: no, I don't have any host check. 
i just have apache 2 running which works as a reverse proxy

Comment: Does the error originate from CF, or your instance? If you are not sure, you can you login to the instance and check apache logs for errors or connection details.

Comment: could you help me out with this?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66327053/passing-an-dynamic-data-html-template-with-ses-lambda-notification

Comment: @sumanthshetty Sadly, I'm not using SES that much, and can't help with this question.